# How to disable default nil-initialization of Optional

Tags: swift, option-type

Let's say I have these two structures:

```
struct DataOne {
    let id: String
    // ...
}
struct DataTwo {
    let id: String
    // ...
}
```

And there is a separate conversion function:

```
extension DataOne {
    func convertToDataTwo() -> DataTwo {
        .init(
            id: self.id,
            // ...
        )
    }
}
```

At some point, the `var name: String?` field is added to both structures:

```
struct DataOne {
    let id: String
    var name: String?
    // ...
}
struct DataTwo {
    let id: String
    var name: String?
    // ...
}
```

But the assembly does not swear because the field is optional.
And when converting, the `name` field is lost.
Is it possible to disable the autofill of the option or to call the warnings?
I tried to find such a rule in SwiftLint, but I didn't find it.

Comment: It shouldn't compile if you add the `name` field https://swift.godbolt.org/z/nazbGW14d

Comment: Yes, you're right. There you need to specify `var name: String?`, then don't swear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `var`'s type is written `T?` with no default value, and Swift synthesizes a memberwise `init` for your type, then the synthesized `init` uses a default value of `nil` for that `var`.

However, if your `var`'s type is written `Optional<T>` with no default value, then the synthesized `init` does **not** use a default value.

So write this instead:

```
struct DataOne {
    let id: String
    var name: Optional<String>
    // ...
}

struct DataTwo {
    let id: String
    var name: Optional<String>
    // ...
}
```

Or write out your `init` instead of letting the compiler synthesize it:

```
struct DataOne {
    let id: String
    var name: String?

    init(id: String, name: String?) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }
}

struct DataTwo {
    let id: String
    var name: String?

    init(id: String, name: String?) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

You can use Xcode's Editor > Refactor > Generate Memberwise Initializer command to write most of the `init` for you, then delete the  `= nil` default:

[image: demonstration of using Generate Memberwise Initializer]